# writing a private key from a variable to file

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, ssh, echo

I have a scenario where I am exporting private key and writing it to a file.

```
export CLI_KEY_FILE="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

In shell script I am doing this as below

```
echo -e $CLI_KEY_FILE > $HOME/pvtkey.pem
```

after that when I open the pvtkey.pem file I see the format is completely changed
and also authenticating with that gives error `The provided key is not a private key, or the provided passphrase is incorrect.`
Note: I am not using any passphrase

How can I correctly output the exported variable of private key in a file.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It must be a duplicate. Use `"$CLI_KEY_FILE" `

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Did not understand by duplicate